# What is the effectiveness of using companion plants for pest control?

Tags: companion-planting

How effective is basil as a companion plant for pest control? Would the benefits outweigh the ease of mono-cropping, such as being able to use cat's cradle trellis for tomatoes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the herb section on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_companion_plants) large table of companion plants.

> Basil... is said to make tomatoes taste better

[This other site](http://www.tomatodirt.com/companion-plants.html) seems to be more informative and lists the specific pests basil will deter.

> Repels whiteflies, mosquitoes, spider mites, aphids, hornworms

Comment: Thanks tM! The resource you provided was quite specific and had useful tips.